# Resetting the database in Rails 4

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

So I made a new branch in git to continue my rails study as suggested in Michael Hartl's 3rd edition. I used rails console to create a new user so that I could setup the user page (at this time we did not have the sign up form). So per instructions it says

> Since we’re about to add the ability to create new users through the
>   web, let’s remove the user created at the console in Section 6.3.4.
>   The cleanest way to do this is to reset the database with `bundle exec rake db:migrate:reset`

I was under the impression that `db:reset` is suppose to dump the current database and rebuild it from the schema.rb, but for me it deletes everything in my schema leaving it blank and I have to copy an earlier version of my schema from another branch.

Is there something I'm not doing correctly or overlooking? I thought I understood the db::xxxx commands but apparently not as well as I fooled myself into thinking ha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, this is the expected behavior. The test data resets every time you run the tests unless you provide seed date. You should check out Factory Girl to build objects for your test database: https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl

Hartl covers Factory Girl later in the book/tutorial, so you might not have gotten to that part yet.

So you are partially correct; rake db:reset will rebuild your schema, but all the data will be destroyed. It's a bad idea to use a copy of an existing database for testing purposes.

To rebuild the schema I usually run:

```
rake db:test:prepare
```

Works every time.

Comment: So what does one do in that situation exactly? I didn't have migrations to fall back on and my seed.rb was empty as well so the end result for me was getting errors stating "could not find table 'Users'" which made me panic.

Comment: You will have to recreate the migration that builds the user table. Did you use a migration to build the user table for your development db? i guess the point is that the development, test, and production databases are completely separate entities.